# ¿Es afinmente o afínmente?

Tags: adverbios, acentuación

En matemáticas usamos la palabra *afinmente*, no creo que realmente sea una palabra en español.

Mi pregunta es si se acentúa, ¿o no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afín (aguda terminada en n) + mente = afínmente

A menos que la rae dle diga lo contrario. ¿Por qué la duda? ¿Surgió una nueva regla de acentuación?

Answer (score 2):

Es una palabra válida en español, construida a partir del adjetivo **[afín](https://dle.rae.es/af%C3%ADn)** y la partícula *-mente*, lo cual da lugar a un adverbio.

Según la Ortografía de la RAE, llevaría acento, como nos indica [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/adverbios-acabados-en-mente-acentuacion/)

> Los adverbios acabados en –mente solo llevan tilde si el adjetivo del
> que derivan también la lleva.
>
> Tal como explica la [Ortografía](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QespkHoczZURfcSA), «estas palabras presentan de manera
> excepcional dos sílabas tónicas: la del adjetivo base y la de la
> terminación», y esto justifica que se escriban con tilde si también la
> había en el adjetivo del que proceden.